# file_picker allowedExtensions filter dosent work

Tags: android, flutter, filepicker

i using extention file_picker in flutter width extention filter

```
try {
      result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'heic', 'pdf'],
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('fileSelector ****${e}***');
    }
```

but in Android i can select all files width any extension. In IOS work this filter fine. Is it a bug in `file_picker` or do I have to do something additional?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/FAQ